# How to invoke an mdichildA method that invokes an mdichildB method from mdiparent

Tags: vb.net, mdi

I have an MDIParent form containing previous and next buttons in the toolbar.  MDIChildA contains a DataGridView, and MDIChildB or MDIChildC forms display the properties of a selected row based upon the row type.  All MDI child forms are shown with DocStyle.Fill.

The objective is for the previous and next buttons to invoke methods in MDIChildA, and for MDIChildA to refresh either MDIChildB or MDIChildC for the next DataGridView row depending upon the row type.

The MDIChildC form was recently introduced when a second type of item was included in the DataGridView.  The previous and next functions were working when there was only one row type.  Here's how next was coded:

In MDIParent:

```
    Private Delegate Sub InvokePrevNext()

    Private Sub tsbNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbNext.Click
        Try
            If Not ActiveMdiChild Is Nothing Then
                Dim frm As Object
                frm = Me.ActiveMdiChild
                Dim dlg As InvokePrevNext = AddressOf frm.MoveNext
                dlg.Invoke()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            ' ignore exceptions
        End Try
    End Sub
```

In MDIChildB:

```
    Public Sub MoveNext()
        Call psMovePreviousNext(pMDIChildA.NextRowPrimaryKey)
    End Sub
```

(When MDIChildB was initially invoked, it received MDIChildA ByRef and saved its pointer.)

Now that an MDIChildC form exists, I need to reorient control so that MDIChildA handles the next request by determining the next row type and refreshing the appropriate child.  It seems to me that I can no longer use the ActiveMDIChild approach.

Can anyone suggest an approach?

Comment: Is there only MDIChildA, MDIChildB and MDIChildC, or could there also be a Child D, E, F, etc. ?  Is ChildA always displaying the grid and child B/C always handle display?

Comment: Yes, those are the only three.  There are two types of rows in the ChildA grid, and I need separate child forms to display their properties.  I'd like to avoid the overhead of unloading and reloading the forms, if possible.

Comment: And just to be clear, I don't want ChildA to be visible when the row changes - I just want the properties of the next row to appear automatically in the appropriate child form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since MDIChildA has a specific purpose (showing the grid) and provides information for other forms (MDIChildB or MDIChildC) you could just keep a reference to the instance of MDIFormA in MDIParent (private childA AS MDIChildA).  Then in your `tsbNext_Click` you could call a public function on `childA` (an instance of MDIChildA), to return the selected row info, which can be subsequently passed to MDIChildB or MDIChildC, etc.

In MDIParent:

```
Private childA As MDIChildA 'assigned when MDIChildA is loaded/shown
Private childB As MDIChildB 'assigned when MDIChildB is loaded/shown
Private childC As MDIChildC 'assigned when MDIChildC is loaded/shown

Private Sub tsbNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbNext.Click
    Try
        If childA IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim nextRow = childA.GetNextRow()
            If nextRow = [you know what goes here, I dont] Then
                childB.FillData(nextRow)
            Else
                childC.FillData(nextRow)
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Ignoring exceptions is not recommended 
        ' because it makes it hard to support your app
        ' You are better-off logging it. Check out Log4Net 
    End Try
End Sub
```

In MDIChildA:

```
Public Function GetNextRow() As String 'or DataRow or enum or something
    'code to pick the next row
    return me.NextRowPrimaryKey
End Sub
```

In MDIChildB or MDIChildC:

```
Public Sub MoveNext(nextRow As String) 'or Long or DataRow, etc.
    'code for processing the nextrow
End Sub
```

Comment: Of course.  I got too tunneled into the code to see the obvious big picture.  Many thanks tgolisch!